# How to interpret "wollen" in the phrase "es will ... + Intransitive Verb"

Tags: meaning

> **Es will** mir nicht **gelingen**, etw. zu tun.
>
> **Es will** mir **scheinen**, dass ...
>
> **Es will** mir nicht **einleuchten**, warum ...

I wonder if the meaning of "wollen" in these instances should still be interpreted as "want" or it deviates somewhat from pure and simple "want"?

What does "wollen" add to the meanings of these sentences, exactly?

Comment: As far as your first sentence, perhaps it is _  jmdm. gelingt es, etw.Akk. zu tun   Infinitiv: gelingen_ (http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/gelingen) that you're dealing with.

Comment: Actually, it is not the meanings of these sentences but rather the function of "wollen" that troubles me here. As for "gelingen", you could just as well phrase a sentence without "wollen", after all: "Wenn es uns gelingt, etw. zu tun".

Comment: Your first sentence is translated like this here (https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/german-english/gelingen#gelingen_1): "es will mir nicht gelingen ... zu ..." "I can't seem to manage to ..." Interestingly, "wollen" is rendered as "can" in this example. Never seen that.

Comment: Rather than a single word "can", it seems to me more like: "I **can't seem to** do something, now matter how hard / how many times I try". The persistence of inability, if you will: "**Fate** does **not want** me to succeed, no matter what".

Comment: Involving *fate* is maybe a bit over-analyzing things. "Das Auto will nicht anspringen" makes the car *taking responsibility* as if it were a person you can easily blame.

Answer (score 2):

This is maybe a German speciality of being able to *impersonate* a problem / statement / inanimate object in an expression.

> Das Auto *will nicht anspringen*
>
> Die Lösung für dieses Problem *will gut überlegt sein*
>
> Nicht enden *wollender* Beifall
>
> Es *will* mir nicht einleuchten, dass ...
>
> Das Buch *will* ein Ratgeber für alle Lebenslagen sein.

This extends the meaning of *wollen* which would normally denote a person's desire towards something onto inanimate objects - obviously, there is no *desire* involved here, but rather only a "doesn't work", or a "must be".

Looking specifically at the difference between

> Es leuchtet mir einfach nicht ein, dass ...

and

> Es will mir einfach nicht einleuchten, dass ...

the second wording clearly denotes a *fundamental* and *persistent* problem of non-understanding, whereas the first *could* mean only a temporary problem (maybe I just haven't had enough coffee yet). Other than that, it kind of shifts the cause and responsibility of non-understanding more towards the problem and away from myself (blame the problem if you don't get it).

Note this approach doesn't only work with *wollen* but with other verbs as well:

> Die Schraube weigert sich einfach aufzugehen.
>
> Das Problem wehrt sich gegen eine ordentliche Lösung.

Comment: Hi. What do you think of the point I have mentioned in the comment above? (the 4th comment)